# Generalized uncertainty principle and relevant energy scales

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-gravity

To include quantum gravity effects, some research works have suggested a deformation of the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. One particular model has, $$[\hat{x},\hat{p}]=i\hbar\left(1+\frac{\beta}{m_pc}\hat{p}^2\right).\tag{1}$$ One benefit of such deformation is that a minimum conceivable length, or the Planck length, comes about naturally in the theory. To see this we apply Heisenberg's uncertainty principle $$(\Delta x)^2(\Delta p)^2\geq\left|\langle[\hat{x},\hat{p}]\rangle\right|^2.$$ In the ground state $\langle\hat{p}\rangle=0$, we can write $\langle\hat{p}^2\rangle=\Delta p^2$. Thus, the uncertainty relation corresponding to equation $(1)$ is as follows, $$\Delta x\geq i\hbar\left(\frac{1}{\Delta p}+\frac{\beta}{m_pc}\Delta p\right).$$ Therefore, the minimum uncertainty in position is, $$\Delta x_{\text{min}}=2\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{m_pc}},$$ which can be set of the sclae of Planck length. Therefore, the above commutation relation with deformation seems phenomenologically important to test quantum gravity signaures in the laboratories. However, I have not read much about this deformed uncertainty principle or the Generalised Uncertainty Principle as it is called any more than I have presented here. And I am particularly confused about the energy scale in which this deformation works. If anyone has worked along this line, then kindly clarify the my doubts I mention below.

The commutation relation as can be seen is not manifestly Lorentz invariant. Thus, am I to assume that we are working in the non-relativistic regime? If not, and most probably not because we are probing at high energy in expectation that at high energy gravitational effects would be important for quantum mechanics, then why not use a relativistic version of the commutator? Moreover, as in high energy with energy uncertainty $\Delta E\geq 2mc^2$ particle description of quantum mechanics breaks down and one needs to use the quantum field theory, then why are we using this particle quantum mechanics to describe high energy phenomena?

Therefore, as one can see I am totally confused about the scale involved in this physics, if one elaborates the scales of this theory, that would be most helpful.